# How to grant access on all private fields values retrieved by reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

Is it possible to get a fields' value, without using `field.setAccessible(true);`?

```
 Field field = object.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);    
 field.setAccessible(true);
 Object value = field.get(object);
```

I mean, could I simply grant access to all private fields of a specific class, without having to invoke the setter on each read?

Comment: No, you could not. What's for? You could prepare `Field` object(s) once, cache it and use it for reading multiple times.

Comment: I thought for performance reasons. Because I'm using reflection to generate a flat key-value like map based on complex beans. When generating from a bean, I hoped being able to skip the `setAccessible()` so I wouldn't have to set it on each property on each mapping.

Comment: Maybe if you fetched the fields array and loop through it in a way (streams, lists, plain loop, ...) ?

Comment: So, just reuse `Field` objects for reading then.

Comment: @kan could you be more specific on reuse?

Comment: Replied as answer with code.

Answer (score 4):

You don’t have to repeat that operation for every field access. You only have to do it once per class/field, but there is an efficient way to do it:

```
static final class Accessor extends ClassValue<Map<String,Field>> {
    @Override protected Map<String, Field> computeValue(Class<?> type) {
        Field[] fields=type.getDeclaredFields();
        AccessibleObject.setAccessible(fields, true);
        Map<String,Field> map=new HashMap<>(fields.length);
        for(Field f: fields) map.put(f.getName(), f);
        return map;
    }
}
static final Accessor FIELD_ACCESSOR = new Accessor();
```

which makes your access as simple as

```
Object value = FIELD_ACCESSOR.get(o.getClass()).get(fieldName).get(o);
```

Note that `ClassValue` takes care of performing the operation only once per class, while the cached values do not prevent class garbage collection, and `AccessibleObject.setAccessible(…)` will be applied to all declared fields at once.

But keep in mind, that these are the declared fields of the actual class only, you will have to iterate the super class hierarchy manually to search their fields. Field names don’t have to be unique through the class hierarchy.

Comment: So in short - `AccessibleObject.setAccessible(object.getClass().getDeclaredFields(), true)`? Didn't know that trick before, thanks!

Comment: @Janez Kuhar: well, you have to keep the `Field[]` array, as the next call to `Class.getDeclared‌Fields()` will return a new array of new `Field` instances, not being accessible. The accessible property is bound to a specific `Field` instance, other `Field` instances representing the same field may have a different accessible state.

Answer (score 1):

No, you could not. What's for? You could prepare Field object(s) once, cache it and use it for reading multiple times.

```
 // do it once
 Field field = object.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);    
 field.setAccessible(true);

 // use many times:
 for(million times)
     Object value = field.get(object);
```

Comment: I know I can retrieve the field on the *same* object multiple times without having to invoke the setter. But if the `object` changes, means a new object was created, I have to invoke the setter again, right?

Comment: fields are for classes, not for objects. You could have fields per `getClass()`. Have a cache too.

Comment: So I could create a `Set<Field> cache` and put the field there after calling `setAccessible()`. And then calling `cache.get(field).get(object)` to access the value of new objects. Is that what you'd suggest?

Comment: Yes, but not exactly. You could have a cache such as `Map<Class, Map<String, Field>>`. I.e. class -> fieldName -> field.